# Ubuntu 12.10 Minecraft Bukkitt Server Settings/Plugins

Tags: settings, plugins, minecraft

I recently installed a Craftbukkit basic server on my Ubuntu 12.10 system. Note I did this without the desktop/gnome, all done on the command line. Now that I have the basic server I really need help with on how to edit the server settings and how to install/edit the settings of the plugins. There really isn't anything I could find on Google so I need all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command line `nano` or `vim` editors. Both allow you to edit the config files from the command line. Bukkit config files are located in your server directory and plugin config files are usually located in the

```
SERVER_DIR/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/
```

directory

Your server directory (place where the `craftbukkit.jar`) should look something like this
`ls -1shgGFB --group-directories-first`:

```
total 13M
   0 drwx------ 1    0 Sep  6 17:28 cache/
4.0K drwx------ 1 4.0K Sep  6 17:45 plugins/
4.0K drwx------ 1 4.0K Sep  6 17:45 world/
4.0K drwx------ 1 4.0K Sep  6 17:45 world_nether/
4.0K drwx------ 1 4.0K Sep  6 17:45 world_the_end/
 512 -rw------- 1  107 Sep  6 17:44 banned-ips.txt
 512 -rw------- 1  107 Sep  6 17:44 banned-players.txt
4.0K -rw------- 1 1.1K Sep  6 17:44 bukkit.yml
 13M -rw------- 1  13M Sep  6 16:01 craftbukkit-1.5.2-R1.0.jar
4.0K -rw------- 1 2.6K Sep  6 17:28 help.yml
   0 -rw------- 1    0 Sep  6 17:44 ops.txt
   0 -rw------- 1    0 Sep  6 17:29 permissions.yml
 44K -rw------- 1  42K Sep  6 17:45 server.log
 512 -rw------- 1  502 Sep  6 17:45 server.properties
4.0K -rw------- 1 1.6K Sep  6 17:44 wepif.yml
   0 -rw------- 1    0 Sep  6 17:28 white-list.txt
```

and the `plugins/` folder in your server folder should look like this, with config folders in their plugin's own folder, for example, Essentials's config file will be at `plugins/Essentials/config.yml` (filename may vary for each plugin)
`ls -1shgGFB --group-directories-first`:

```
total 8.5M
 4.0K drwx------ 1  4.0K Sep  6 17:29 AuthMe/
 4.0K drwx------ 1  4.0K Sep  6 17:45 CraftBook/
 4.0K drwx------ 1  4.0K Sep  6 17:29 Essentials/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:29 Jail/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:42 Lockette/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:28 Modifyworld/
 4.0K drwx------ 1  4.0K Sep  6 17:54 PermissionsEx/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:29 PluginMetrics/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:28 Simple Prefix/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:44 Towny/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:45 WorldEdit/
    0 drwx------ 1     0 Sep  6 17:44 WorldGuard/
 224K -rw------- 1  224K Sep  6 17:33 1372097400wpdm_Towny_Advanced.zip
 856K -rw------- 1  856K Sep  6 17:23 AuthMe.jar
1000K -rw------- 1 1000K Sep  6 17:24 CraftBook_3.6.9.zip
 1.1M -rw------- 1  1.1M Jun 20 07:17 CraftBook.jar
  16K -rw------- 1   13K Jun 18 00:21 EssentialsAntiBuild.jar
  12K -rw------- 1   12K Jun 18 00:21 EssentialsChat.jar
 832K -rw------- 1  831K Jun 18 00:21 Essentials.jar
  20K -rw------- 1   18K Jun 18 00:21 EssentialsProtect.jar
  16K -rw------- 1   15K Jun 18 00:21 EssentialsSpawn.jar
 836K -rw------- 1  836K Sep  6 17:23 Essentials.zip
 148K -rw------- 1  146K Sep  6 17:22 Jail.jar
 8.0K -rw------- 1  5.1K Sep  6 16:38 LANBroadcaster.jar
  60K -rw------- 1   57K Sep  6 17:37 Lockette.jar
  28K -rw------- 1   26K Sep  6 17:22 Modifyworld.jar
 176K -rw------- 1  173K Sep  6 17:22 PermissionsEx.jar
  44K -rw------- 1   44K Jun  5  2012 Questioner.jar
  12K -rw------- 1   12K Sep  6 17:23 SimplePrefix.jar
 568K -rw------- 1  568K Sep  6 17:41 Towny_Advanced.zip
 484K -rw------- 1  483K Jun 24 18:52 Towny.jar
 784K -rw------- 1  783K Sep  6 17:43 worldedit-5.5.7.zip
 820K -rw------- 1  817K Jul  2 08:47 WorldEdit.jar
 312K -rw------- 1  310K Sep  6 17:36 worldguard-5.7.5.zip
 320K -rw------- 1  319K May 26 17:19 WorldGuard.jar
```

Comment: Ok I have installed nano but I need more help finding the files. Such as I just installed PermissionsEx a plugin for Bukkit and I need th find it and then place it in the folder or directory in the bukkit plugin folder.

Comment: Use `mkdir NAME` to make a folder and `mv SOURCE DEST` to move files

Comment: @ebank36 You need to find where you downloaded the file then `mv "FILE" "SERVER_DIR/plugins/"`. How experienced are you with the command line?

Comment: thank you so far you've helped a lot but I think the last thing is I downloaded permissionsex with wget then the direct download link. It downloaded and said saving to index.html. I then moved the index.html to the plugins folder. The problem is, is that the index.html isn't the actual permissionsex.jar its just a bunch of lines of coding any ideas on what to do?

Comment: nevermind I used the wrong download direct link